# CasperJS; opening dynamic url

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am using casperJS to got ta a page and collect an id from the URL, this is what my start function is doing.  I would then like to put the id in to a new url and go there.

This works for the `user` var, this is coming in from the terminal. However `sid` is undefined and not the value I updated it to.

Any help would be appreciated. I am wondering if I found a limitation with casperJS.  please not that this is not the full code (as that is much longer), if you message me I can provide you the whole script.

```
var user = decodeURIComponent(casper.cli.get(0).replace(/\+/g, ' '))

var sid 
casper.start('https://editor.storify.com/', function() {
    sid = this.getCurrentUrl()
    sid = sid.split('/')[3]
})
casper.thenOpen('https://storify.com/' + sid, function() {
   console.log('lets view the posts')
   console.log(token)
   console.log(sid)
   if (dev)
      this.capture('storeheading.png')   
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this problem by warping the `thenOpen` inside of a `then`

```
casper.then(function() {
  casper.thenOpen('https://storify.com/' + sid, function() {
  console.log('lets view the posts')
  console.log(token)
  console.log(sid)
  if (dev)
    this.capture('storeheading.png')   
  })
})
```